# Batch - How to get multiple user input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that have to process 2 user input

```
SET /p LeftInput=Enter First Photo Number: 
SET /A PhotoLeft=LeftInput

SET /p RightInput=Enter Second Photo Number: 
SET /A PhotoRight=RightInput
```

I can get the first parameter !PhotoLeft! but, I can't get second parameters !PhotoRight! (It always null)

How to archieve this?

Thank You.

Comment: works fine for me...

Comment: You don't need to use `SET /A` at all because you are not doing arithmetic. You are also pointlessly setting variables, you should only need two lines: `Set/P "PhotoLeft=Enter First Photo Number: "` and `Set/P "PhotoRight=Enter Second Photo Number: "`. _The biggest difficulty is in ensuring that the user input exactly matches your required input format/criteria_.